# The gzuncompress of php equivalent on javascript

Tags: javascript, php, zip, compression

I have a php file that do:

```
echo(gzcompress("TEST COMPRESS"));
```

and on javascript i do a request on php and i want a function that
do the same of gzuncompress(data) for take the result = "TEST COMPRESS" again on client side.

EDIT:
Thank you @aaronk6, zlib worked!

If someone ready this question, the zlib will works if the php is with gzencode(), gzcompress will not work.

Comment: Use HTTP GZip compression; you don't need to do that.

Comment: Hello, is not for http, is for phonegap, i need a function :D

Comment: Requests in PhoneGap are still HTTP requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SLaks pointed out, this is might be pointless, however here’s an answer to your question.

Browsers do **not** have a uncompress method that is accessible from JavaScript, so there’s no equivalent. When you want to decompress gzipped data in JavaScript, you will need to use a JavaScript implementation of the gzip algorithm.

There’s [zlib.js](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js) which seems to be capable of doing this.

Comment: Heyyy Thank you!  Worked Perfect!!
I just had tochange in php the gzcompress() to gzencode() and works the Zlib.Gunzip(data).decompress()

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP running on your server, and you want to decompress a **zlib-compressed string** in Javascript, an alternative to using the `zlib.js` library would be to use the `Fetch API` to re-contact the server and then simply `gzuncompress()` using PHP.

**Example:**

```
const decompressString = async (compressedString) => {

  const decompressionScriptFilepath = '/decompress-string.php';
  const compressedStringToSend = { method: 'POST', body: compressedString };
  const response = await fetch(decompressionScriptFilepath, compressedStringToSend);

  return await response.text();
}
```

**PHP Script at `/decompress-string.php`**

```
<?php

  $Compressed_String = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $decompressedString = gzuncompress($Compressed_String);
  echo $decompressedString;

?>
```

Then you simply need to invoke the javascript function:

```
decompressString('eNoLycgsVgCiRIWS1OISPYWQUf4of5Q/yh/lj/JH+aP8wc0HAERY4KM=');
```